# Using *only* pointers to print the contents of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have been asked to write a function that prints the content of an array after the `x`th element (as in, `x` and forth, as `x` is a pointer inside the array). I am not allowed to use `[]` for anything other than initialization, and not allowed to create variables inside the function - I may only use what the function receives from the main, which is the length (`int n`), the array (`int* arr`) and element `x` (`int* x`).

My question is how can I print `x` and forth in the array using only pointers without an index from a loop?

Here is what I wrote:

```
void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{
    if ((arr <= x) && (x < arr + n))
    {
        while(x < (arr + n))
        {
            printf("%8d", *(arr+x));        //I know you can't do this
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

For this:

```
    int arr[] = { 0,5,6,7,8,4,3,6,1,2 };
    int n=10;
    int* x = (arr+3);

    printAfterX(arr, n, x);
```

The output should be:

```
7 8 4 3 6 1 2
```

**Edit: Thanks y'all for the help! Works just fine. :)**

Comment: is `n` the total length of the array or the number of characters to print?

Comment: If `x` is a pointer to a value you can use `printf("%8d", *(arr + *x)` (dereference `x`)

Comment: @atturri no, I only print from arr[x] until the end of the array

Comment: _I am not allowed to use []_ : this requirement is rather ... fishy

Comment: Is array sorted and has distinct elements?

Comment: @AlterMann , That flashes an error.."...Violating location"

Comment: @Nico x is a pointer to a certain address of one of the elements in the array, for example, int* x = arr+3

Comment: dereferencing `x` you'll get the value you want to print... I guess

Comment: What is `x`, an array of `int`'s, a value passed using `&value`?

Comment: Please show how you call `printAfterX` as well as the expected output.

Comment: The problem description cannot be right, `arr` and `x` cannot be both `int *` and expect to print `arr[x]`

Comment: @AlterMann x isn't an array..

Comment: @fishy _x isn't an array_ : then what is it?

Comment: @MichaelWalz it is a pointer to one of the elements in the array, for example, int* x = arr+3

Comment: @atturri well, these are the insturctions I got.. it's not exactly arr[x], but x and forth inside the array, as x is a pointer inside the array

Comment: You can't call `printAfterX` with `*x`, the example is wrong

Comment: So it seems you just want to print `*x`, not `*(arr + x)` which is incorrect.

Comment: @atturri ok, so how should I call it?

Comment: @ringø well, not exactly, as x contains the address of the element in the array..

Comment: @fishy tbh, there are many things that need to be fixed before the question makes sense. The `arr` in the caller is an array of pointers, so the values don't seem to make much sense. Then following that example `x` should be a double pointer, and so on... You first need a problem and a caller that makes sense if we are to fix the function.

Comment: @CiaPan, you are right!!

Comment: @fishy I can see you tried to fix the code, but it still contains errors. Does it even compile? Turn warnings on, the compiler should tell you that something is still wrong.

Comment: @CiaPan well now it does

Comment: Not yet remove the asterisk from the `arr` declaration on the caller and all the answers you got will start working.

Comment: `int* arr[] = { 0,5,6,7,8,4,3,6,1,2 };` is wrong, it should be `int arr[] = { 0,5,6,7,8,4,3,6,1,2 };`

Comment: @MichaelWalz fixed

Comment: Well, as it seems, it's nevertheless the solution you accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{
    arr += n;               // make arr to point past the last element of the array
    for( ; x < arr; x++)    // walk till the end of array
        printf("%8d", *x);  // print the current item
}
```

Example https://ideone.com/Ea3ceT

Comment: @fishy It won't happen when you fix errors in your `main()` routine.

Comment: yeah, I fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Well it works now and doesn't show any warnings or errors..? Maybe I didn't update the question like my code is now.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{
  while(x < (arr + n))
  {
      printf("%d ", *x);
      x++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = { 0,5,6,7,8,4,3,6,1,2 };
  int n = 10;
  int *x = (arr+3);

  printAfterX(arr, n, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, it doesn't return anything so why should it be int? Usually it's not a problem when I do my homework?

Comment: @fishy maybe it's time to learn how to use the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: I'm kinda new to VS, I used Notepad++ until like..recently.

Comment: @fishy don't worry about `int main()` the C standard wants `int main()` but most of the time `void main()` works too.

Comment: @fishy how do you compile your program ?

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger, it's very easy, it allows you to step through the code, inspect variables etc.

Comment: I suppose I should... :/

Answer (score -1):

Change the `printf` line for this:

```
printf("%8d", *x);
```

Comment: That makes VS flash an error "..Access violation reading location"

Comment: Remove the asterisk from `x` in the line you call `printAfterX`. Your caller function is wrong.

Comment: yes yes, my call was wrong but I fixed it, didn't I? :/